# How can I rearrange some time series in python?

Tags: python, imshow

I have 100 time series that I have shown with "imshow" in python like this (the colors show the amplitude of each time series). I want to rearrange them according the higher frequencies. what should I do?

[image]

Comment: What did you try?  Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your 2D matrix into a numpy matrix:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(your_2d_matrix)
```

Then, using numpy, you can sort on any axis to acquire the desired result:

```
a = a.sort(axis = 1)
```

As also explained [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.sort.html).

Comment: I don't have the values of frequencies in my matrix. the elements of each row in my matrix shows the amplitude of each signals over time steps. I calculate their frequencies separately and depend on frequencies I want to rearrange them.